# Código que permita realizar capturas sobre una pagina web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Saludos!

Algún código que permita realizar capturas sobre una pagina web y luego escribir y dibujar sobre la captura...

Comment: Creo que buscando en google vas a encontrar más respuestas para eso que preguntandolo aquí. Saludos

Comment: Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Con este proyecto en github: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas

**Hechale in vistazo a este codigo:**

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  }
});
```

Te dejo la version [DEMO](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html)